# Error: advanced-http value must be string Ionic

Tags: api, http, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have try to user @angular/http to send my api but I got the 401 polyfills error so I change it to @ionic-native/http , but then I got yet another error which is :Error: advanced-http value must be string" so I log my header and it was empty???

The log

```
"normalizedNames": {},
  "lazyUpdate": [
    {
      "name": "Authorization",
      "value": "Basic xxxxxxxx",
      "op": "a"
    },
    {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "op": "a"
    }
  ],
  "headers": {},
  "lazyInit": {
    "normalizedNames": {},
    "lazyUpdate": null,
    "headers": {}
  }
```

mycode

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';

 constructor(public http: HTTP) {}

  login(username, password) {

    let body = {
      username: username,
      password: password
    };
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic xxxxxx');
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
return this.http.post(apiUrl, body, { headers: headers })
  .then(data => {

    console.log(data.status);
  console.log(data.data); // data received by server
    console.log(data.headers);

  })
  .catch(error => {

   console.log(error); // error message as string

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

add this to your app.module

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  HttpClientModule,
  IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
],
```

then in your code

```
//import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

 constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

  login(username, password) {

    let body = {
      username: username,
      password: password
    };
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic xxxxxx');
    headers = headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
return this.http.post(apiUrl, body, { headers: headers })
  .subscribe(data => {

    console.log(data.status);
  console.log(data.data); // data received by server
    console.log(data.headers);

  })
  .catch(error => {

   console.log(error); // error message as string

  });
```

Comment: I was using HttpClient, but it did not work with me my header is still empty and it give me polyfills.js:3 OPTIONS 401 error and Failed to load http://link// Response for preflight does not have HTTP ok status.

Answer (score 0):

thread quite old but might be can help others. Change your headers like below and test.

```
return this.http.post(apiUrl, body, { headers: 'Content-Type: application/json', Authorization: 'Basic xxx'})....
```